# RoR Map array with selection from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, dictionary

I make select

```
m_repeats = Event.all
```

Then I need change the shedule (it is date field) in each element. I need set year and month for current (date)

I try to do:

```
m_repeats.map{ |elem| elem.schedule.year = date.year, elem.schedule.month = date.month }
```

But I get the errors:

```
undefined method `month=' for Wed, 03 Apr 2013:Date
```

How I may change they by map?

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'month=' method for Date class. I guess this will work,

```
m_repeats.map{ |elem| elem.schedule = Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, elem.schedule.day)}
```

Comment: Now I get  ArgumentError in EventsController#index

invalid date

Comment: Setting the 31st in a month that doesn't have 31 days?

Comment: If I set mr = m_repeats.map{ |elem| elem.shedule = Date.new(date.year, date.month, date.day)}  it is undefined method `shedule' for Mon, 01 Apr 2013:Date. So I think the problem is that I can't use name of field at the mapping?